# JQuery Slider - remembering values between pages ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

How can I remember values from a JQuery slider and set them to what the user had selected when the page changes?

I'm using a JQuery slider, when a button is clicked a new page loads and these sliders are on that page as well. When that pages loads I need to set the sliders to the same values that were selected on previous page. I also need these values to stay when the user go back to the previous page.

At the moment it just resets back to the defaults that I set.

I have the values stored in session on button click

```
Session["TermYears"] = hdYears.Value.ToString();
```

but I don't know how to set the values when the page loads using JQuery.

I have a hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdCover" runat="server" />
```

My code is as follows

```
     $(function () {
      $("#coverAmountSlider").slider({
          range: "min",
          value: 150000,
          min: 5000,
          max: 1000000,
          step: 1000,
          slide: function (event, ui) {
              $("#amount").val("£" + ui.value);
              $("#hdCover").val(ui.value);
          }
      });
      $("#amount").val("£" + $("#coverAmountSlider").slider("value"));
      $("#hdCover").val($("#coverAmountSlider").slider("value"));


  });
```

I want to avoid using cookies if possible.

Comment: Try to add a hidden field and keep that value in the hidden field and call that value from slider.

Comment: `localStorage` is also an option if you're supporting IE8+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `localStorage`. You can set/get the values using Javascript very easily.

Maybe try something like this:

```
// Set the localStorage value
$("#coverAmountSlider").slider({
    ... // Your current options
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        localStorage["sliderValue"] = ui.value;
    }
});
```

Now you can retrieve that value from any page:

```
// Get the localStorage value from a different page
var sliderValue = localStorage["sliderValue"];

$("#differentSlider").slider("value", sliderValue);
```

`localStorage` browser compatibility ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)):

- Chrome 4+
- Firefox 3.5+
- IE8+
- Opera 10.40+
- Safari 4+

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, works a treat, I didn't know about localstorage, thanks.